# A Puzzling Riddle

Tags: riddle

A man is sentenced to death. Before his execution, he is allowed to make a statement. If it is false, he will be hanged. If it is true, he will be drowned. What can he say to confuse the jury and save his life?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> He should tell the jury that " you will hang me". If they wanted to hang him the statement is true then they should drown him and if they wanted to drown him the statement is false and the should hang him. By saying that statement the jury is confused and they can not punish him.

Comment: alternatively he could say, "You will not drown me".

Answer (score 1):

He could say

> *"This statement is false."* Or any other self-contradictory statement.